# Module Not Found Error when importing Pytorch_Transformers

Tags: nlp, anaconda, pytorch

After downloading pytorch_transformers through Anaconda and executing the import command through the Jupyter Notebook, I am facing several errors related to missing modules.

I tried searching sacremoses to import the package via Anaconda, but it is only available for Linux machines. Has anyone else faced similar issues? Thanks in advance!

`from pytorch_transformers import BertTokenizer, BertModel, BertForMaskedLM`

This is the error:

---

````
<ipython-input-5-218d0858d00f> in <module>
----> 1 from pytorch_transformers import BertTokenizer, BertModel, BertForMaskedLM

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pytorch_transformers\__init__.py in <module>
      1 __version__ = "1.2.0"
----> 2 from .tokenization_auto import AutoTokenizer
      3 from .tokenization_bert import BertTokenizer, BasicTokenizer, WordpieceTokenizer
      4 from .tokenization_openai import OpenAIGPTTokenizer
      5 from .tokenization_transfo_xl import (TransfoXLTokenizer, TransfoXLCorpus)

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pytorch_transformers\tokenization_auto.py in <module>
     24 from .tokenization_transfo_xl import TransfoXLTokenizer
     25 from .tokenization_xlnet import XLNetTokenizer
---> 26 from .tokenization_xlm import XLMTokenizer
     27 from .tokenization_roberta import RobertaTokenizer
     28 from .tokenization_distilbert import DistilBertTokenizer

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pytorch_transformers\tokenization_xlm.py in <module>
     25 from io import open
     26 
---> 27 import sacremoses as sm
     28 
     29 from .tokenization_utils import PreTrainedTokenizer

ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'sacremoses'```
````

Answer (score 6):

Please try to create a conda environment and install the packages in the created environment using the below steps:

```
conda create -n env_pytorch -c intel python=3.5
source activate env_pytorch
pip install pytorch-transformers
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the reply, unfortunately I'm getting the following error when doing 'pip install pytorch-transformers': ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: python setup.py egg_info Check the logs for full command output.

Answer (score 5):

You are missing the pytorch-transformers dependency. Try installing it with the following command:

```
pip install pytorch-transformers
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using `python -m pip install transformers` rather than using pip install